# No sound on SheepShaver for Windows 10

Tags: emulation, mac-os-classic, sheepshaver

I am running Mac OS 9 through SheepShaver on Windows 10, and I can't get sound to work. I am using an Old World ROM because the New World ROM doesn't work, it causes SheepShaver to crash.

I tried to select the Built-in option in the sound control panel in SheepShaver, but there are no output options.

I have a bunch of ROMs from archive.org, and I'm not sure which one to use IF the ROM is the problem

Comment: not only Windows 10. I believe all Windows versions are affected

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete the Apple Audio Extension.

1. Open your Mac OS 9 HD.
2. Go to System Folder
3. Go to Extensions
4. Move Apple Audio Extension into Trash and empty your trash.
5. Restart SheepShaver
6. Open Sound Panel.
7. Select Built-In.

Comment: Are you sure that deleting the Apple Audio Extension won't remove features?

Comment: It shouldn't. It worked for me.

Comment: There's no Apple Audio Extension in there for me...

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed 9.04 in SheepShaver running on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra and was unable to get the Audio working until I did the steps below.  It might help under windows also, as it's purely a fiddly bit in OS 9.

- From the Apple Menu, select Control Panels -> Sound
- Click on 'Output' (on the left side of the dialog)
- Click on 'Built in' to **select** the output device

This seems ridiculous because the 'built in' device is the only device listed, but somehow it's not *selected* as part of the install process and must be selected (clicked on) manually.  After I did that, my audio worked perfectly.